# Connect Android device to WiFi printer

Tags: android, wifi, network-printers

I want to print my pdf document by my Android phone using wifi on any other way.
or please give me a suggestion about it is possible to connect our Device to wifi printer or send our document for printing.
I hope, I will get best answer or any suggestion from your side as soon as possible.

Comment: No really sure that this is programming related question... Probably need to be moved to other

Comment: Yes it is related to programming i have a work in android related to this think it is the basic requirement of my project.

Comment: no i want to use local printer with out cloud technologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is using [Google Cloud print](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/p/cloudprint.html) on [android](http://androinica.com/2011/01/printing-from-android-with-google-cloud-print-hands-on/)