# How to connect android phone with different types of printer through WIFI (No Google Print Cloud)

Tags: android, android-print-framework

I tried some solutions,for that first I need to install hp printer plugin,I want to do like first my phone wifi scan that printer name,then install its plugin automatically so that user can easily connect to that printer.
Can Anybody help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect Android device to WiFi printer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290839/connect-android-device-to-wifi-printer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can do this by using print share application:
>   **Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); i.setPackage("com.dynamixsoftware.printershare");
>   i.setDataAndType(printFileUri,"text/plain"); startActivity(i);**
>
> where **'printFileUri'** is as follows:
>
> **static final Uri printFileUri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Calci_print.txt");**